# How can i convert java String to javascript string?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

i used these code but nothing seen on document

```
            <%String movie_name ="Matrix"; %>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var movie_name="";
                movie_name= <%= movie_name%>;
                document.write(movie_name);
            </script>
```

so anyone can help me to convert java string to javascript string ?

Comment: Is it a JSP page? Are you setting `request.setAttribute("movie_name", "The Matrix")` or a parameter names `movie_name`? Did you read this [tutorial](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/jsp/jsp_tutorial.html). Did not downvote though.

Comment: oh sorry, I really did not meant to embarrass you. The question looked like it could have been solved by a little more reading of JSP specs or a tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might do it (missing quotes):

```
movie_name="<%= movie_name%>"
```

Also looking at your sample code you can replace it *completely* with:

```
<%= movie_name%>
```

Finally consider using [jstl](/questions/tagged/jstl).

Comment: Quote alone are only enough in a **very** limited set of circumstances.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: are you concerned about escaping? That's why I mentioned about JSTL, e.g. `<c:out value="${movie_name}" escapeXml="true" />`.

Comment: Yes. Just showing putting it in quotes leads the OP down a path that **will** trip him up at some point. And yes, I was just about to add that showing an example of how to do it correctly with the JSTL would be more helpful than just saying "use JSTL". I'd put that in the answer. (Is `escapeXml` **really** the right way to output a JavaScript string literal?)

Answer (score 2):

you need to wrap your output in quotes (I'm assuming this is JSP?)

```
movie_name = "<%= movie_name %>";
```

See, when this is written out the browser tries to interpret it, so without quotes you wind up with something that looks like...

```
movie_name = Men In Black;
```

Since this is obviously a massive syntax fail, the browser just quits trying and silently fails (though you should see a log of what it didn't like).

When you wrap the output in quotes then everything falls into place HOWEVER, make sure to convert any " in your java string to `\"` when you print it out, or you'll have more of the same trouble.

However, as the other answers suggest, you're re-inventing the wheel here and should just do this the prescribed way, as per Nishant's advice.

Comment: Quote alone are only enough in a **very** limited set of circumstances.